# "Exports not defined" error in Svelte when importing Socket.IO client library

Tags: javascript, import, socket.io, svelte, rollup

I'm having problems with the Socket.IO client library that I can't get my head around. When trying to import the library into my main Svelte Component like this

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
```

everything compiles properly, but once I open it in the browser I get an

```
Uncaught Reference error: exports not defined
```

The above way is how the [Socket.IO guides](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html) say, but I also tried different variations like

```
import {io} from 'socket.io-client'

import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
```

and can't get any one of them to work. I supsect it might have to do with how Rollup treats imports and what Module Formats it expects, but I don't have much knowledge in that regard.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example with at least the rollup config. I recommend you codesandbox.